# How to animate flex direction?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm, currently creating the auth page for a project and the design of the auth page uses state to toggle between two panels for sign up and sign in. The image below is what I have so far. Upon clicking the Log In button on the left side, it should swap the left and right panel. I'm doing this using flex-direction row and row-reverse. However, it just sets them rather than smoothly transitions.

[image]

```js
// Imports...
const Auth: React.FC = () => {
  const auth = useAuth()

  const isSignInForm = auth.state === AuthStates.signIn

  const boxStyle = {
    flex: '3',
    bg: 'teal.400'
  }

  return (
    <Flex
      w='100%'
      h='100vh'
      pos='relative'
      flexDir={isSignInForm ? 'row' : 'row-reverse'}
    >
      <Grid flex='4' placeItems='center'>
        // Form stuff... excluded as it is not that important
      </Grid>
      <Box sx={boxStyle}>
        <VStack h='100%' justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
          <Heading fontSize='1rem' as='h1' pb='1rem' color='white'>
            {isSignInForm
              ? 'Don&apos;t Have an Account Yet?'
              : 'Already Signed Up?'}
          </Heading>
          <Button
            variant='outline'
            size='sm'
            w='12rem'
            color='white'
            _hover={{}}
            onClick={() => {
              isSignInForm
                ? auth.updateState(AuthStates.signUp)
                : auth.updateState(AuthStates.signIn)
            }}
          >
            {isSignInForm ? 'Sign Up' : 'Log In'}
          </Button>
        </VStack>
      </Box>
      <Heading
        pos='absolute'
        top='2rem'
        left='2rem'
        color={isSignInForm ? 'teal.500' : 'white'}
        fontSize='xx-large'
      >
        Ideator
      </Heading>
    </Flex>
  )
}

export default Auth
```

Right now, when I click the button, it just swaps the two divs instantly. However, I want it so that they almost slide across. What is an approach I can take to get this effect?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [formal definition of the `flex-direction` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#formal_definition) you'll see that its animation type is [discrete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties#discrete), which means:

> The property's values are not additive, and interpolation swaps from the start value to the end value at 50%.

In other words it jumps instantly from one state to the other state instead of transitioning between the two, as you've noticed.

This means you'll need to use a different property to animate the position of those elements. Consider using [translation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) instead.